# Der Unterschied zwischen Dativ und Akkusativ bei Ortsangaben

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case, wechselpraeposition

Warum heißt es:

> Ich sitze in der Schweiz.

aber

> Ich gehe in die Schweiz.

und

> Ich gehe in die Schule.

und

> Ich gehe in der Schule.

Comment: Ich denke, diese Frage könnte als Anlass genommen werden, zu erklären, was Wechselpräpositionen sind. Ich finde bisher keine gute allgemeine Antwort dazu.

Answer (score 4):

Die meisten Präpositionen, die ein Verhältnis zu einem Ort beschreiben – wie *in, auf, aus, über* u.v.m. –, sind sogenannte *Wechselpräpositionen.* Das heißt, dass sie sowohl den Dativ als auch den Akkusativ nehmen können, aber mit unterschiedlichen Bedeutungen.

### Mit Dativ – Zustand

Wird eine Wechselpräposition mit Dativ verwendet, handelt es sich in der Regel um den Ort *an dem* etwas stattfindet.

> Ich wohne in *der Schweiz.*<sup>{Dat.}</sup>
>
> Montags erreichst du mich auf *der Arbeit.*<sup>{Dat.}</sup>
>
> Der Ballon schwebt über *der Stadt.*<sup>{Dat.}</sup>

Bei *wohnen* dürfte der Fall klar sein: Man wohnt an einem Ort und das über eine längere Zeit, es liegt keine Bewegung vor. Der Ballon bewegt sich ebenfalls nicht oder nicht nennenswert; aus Sicht des Sprechers oder der Schreiberin muss er sich ausreichend lange oberhalb der Stadt aufhalten, dass sich ein Zustand ergibt. Und das dritte Beispiel beschreibt einen Ortszustand *(auf der Arbeit),* der einen ganzen Tag lang anhalten wird.

### Mit Akkusativ – Bewegung

Wird die gleiche Wechselpräposition nun mit dem Akkusativ verwendet, handelt es sich immer um etwas, das als *Bewegung* interpretiert werden kann.

> In zwei Wochen ziehe ich in *die Schweiz.*<sup>{Akk.}</sup>
>
> Immer um neun gehe ich in *das Büro.*<sup>{Akk.}[1]</sup>
>
> Der Ballon schwebt über *die Stadt*<sup>{Akk.}</sup> hinweg.

Im ersten Beispiel dürfte es auch wieder klar sein: *Umziehen* ist ein Prozess mit intrinsischer Bewegung; ich bewege mich von außerhalb in die Schweiz hinein. Auch das zweite Beispiel beschreibt explizit eine Bewegung: Um fünf vor neun werde ich voraussichtlich noch nicht im Büro sein. Und einen Unterschied zum Dativfall kann man im Ballonbeispiel ausmachen: Wird der Akkusativ benutzt, gibt die Sprecherin oder der Schreiber zu erkennen, dass der Ballon die Stadt einmal überquert hat (was zusätzlich durch die Adverbiale *hinweg* verdeutlicht wird.

### Sonderfälle 1: Mit Dativ aber Bewegung

In einigen Fällen wird der Dativ verwendet, obwohl eine Bewegung vorzuliegen scheint. Vergleiche:

> Ich gehe über *die Brücke*<sup>{Akk.}</sup> (hinweg).
>
> Ich gehe unter *der Brücke*<sup>{Dat.}</sup> hindurch.

Das lässt sich folgendermaßen erklären: Der Bereich unter der Brücke wird als ortsfeste Beschreibung verstanden. Diesen ortsfesten Bereich *durchquert* man, man geht *durch ihn*<sup>{Akk.}</sup> hindurch. Ohne *hindurch* (oder einen vergleichbaren Quantifizierer) lässt sich nicht eindeutig ausdrücken, dass man unter der Brücke verschwindet und auf der anderen Seite wieder auftaucht. Im Gegensatz dazu wird bei der Überquerung direkt die Brücke als Vergleichsobjekt herangezogen, deswegen Akkusativ. Außerdem muss man dieses obige Beispiel unterscheiden von:

> Ich gehe unter *die Brücke.*<sup>{Akk.}</sup>

Hier *endet* die Bewegung unter der Brücke, dieser Ort ist also das Ziel.

**Außerdem** gibt es noch eine zweite Gruppe Präpositionen, die den Dativ verlangen, aber eine Bewegung ausdrücken. Es handelt sich um all jene, die eine Bewegung *aus etwas heraus* Beschreiben. Diese Präpositionen sind jedoch keine Wechselpräpositionen, sie verlangen *immer* den Dativ.

> Ich gehe um acht aus *dem Haus.*<sup>{Dat.}</sup>
>
> Komm von *der Leiter*<sup>{Dat.}</sup> runter!

### »Sonderfälle« 2: Zustand aber Akkusativ

> Diese Band fällt unter *das Genre*<sup>{Akk.}</sup> »Symphonic Metal«.

Zugegeben, es gibt nicht viele dieser Beispiele. Und in der Regel handelt es sich um Missverständnisse, was als *Bewegung* zu sehen ist. Man könnte hier argumentieren, dass sich das Musikgenre der Band in letzter Zeit kaum geändert hat, dass sie also stets gleich einsortiert werden sollte, dass deswegen also ein Zustad vorliegt. Das verkennt jedoch das Verb, das in diesem Satz verwendet wird: *fallen.* Der Satz ist vom Aufbau her identisch mit folgendem:

> Mein Einwand fällt unter *den Tisch.*<sup>{Akk.}</sup>

In beiden Fällen haben wir es in Wirklichkeit um eine *Bewegung in etwas hinein* zu tun, die selbstverständlich den Akkusativ verlangt. Beim Tisch – auch wenn es sich um eine feststehende Wendung, die grob *ignorieren* bedeutet, handelt – kann man sich ein Blatt vorstellen, dass von oben herabfällt und dabei unter dem Tisch verschwindet. Die gleiche Argumentation trifft auch auf das Genre zu. Man muss sich das Genre als Kiste oder als Schublade vorstellen, in das ich etwas *hineinsortiere.* Damit dürfte klar sein, warum eine Bewegung vorliegt.

### Vergleiche mit anderen Sprachen

Viele Sprachen, die Prä- oder Postpositionen<sup>[2]</sup> verwenden, drücken die Unterschiede zwischen Bewegung und Zustand durch verschiedene Präpositionen aus. Beispiele:

Englisch:

> I am *in* town. (Zustand)
> The hot-air balloon is *above* the town. (Zustand)
> I am *at* work. (Zustand)
>
> I am going *into* town. (Bewegung)
> The hot-air balloon crosses *over* the town. (Bewegung)
> I am going *to* my office. (Bewegung)

Französisch:

> Je suis *dans* la ville. (Zustand)
>
> Je vais *à* la campagne. (Bewegung)

Andere Sprachen verwenden – unabhängig von Präpositionen – bestimmte Fälle, die entweder einen Zustand oder eine Bewegung ausdrücken. Beispiel Finnisch (die Fallendungen sind kursiv gesetzt):

> Olen kaupungi*ssa.* (»Ich bin in der Stadt«; Zustand)
> Olen kadu*lla.* (»Ich bin auf der Straße«; Zustand)
>
> Menen kaupunki*in.* (»Ich gehe in die Stadt«; Bewegung hinein)
> Menen kadu*lle.* (»Ich gehe auf die Straße«; Bewegung hinauf)
>
> Tulen kaupungi*sta.* (»Ich komme aus der Stadt«; Bewegung heraus)
> Tulen kadu*lta.* (»Ich komme von der Straße«; Bewegung herab)

---

[1]: Besser: *ins* Büro, aber zur Verdeutlichung wurde die Präposition vom Artikel getrennt.

[2]: Im weiteren Verlauf werde ich mich auf *Präpositionen* als generischen Plural von *Prä- oder Postposition* beschränken, da erstere in europäischen Sprachen wesentlich häufiger vorkommen.