# "Die Berge" or "Den Bergen"?

Tags: preposition

Wie sagt man?

> Ich mache eine Wanderung in den Bergen.
>
> Ich wandere in den Bergen.
>
> Ich wandere in die Berge.
>
> Ich gehe in die Berge, um einen Ausflug zu machen.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this? What do you know about the different cases that may go with *in*?

Comment: I've learned German lesser as a month, as I've learned the rule. In most languages I know, except of course English, there is a very clear difference. What is your native language?

Comment: I think with verbs like gehen, fahren, reisen.... you need to use akkusativ, "Ich gehe in die Berge", with others don't "Ich singe in den Bergen" (dativ), but what about wandern?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Der Unterschied zwischen Dativ und Akkusativ bei Ortsangaben](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/31705/der-unterschied-zwischen-dativ-und-akkusativ-bei-ortsangaben)

Answer (score 12):

> *in* + Dativ

bedeutet *wo* etwas stattfindet.

> *in* + Akkusativ

bedeutet *wohin* eine Handlung stattfindet.

> Ich wandere in den Bergen.

(= ich bin bereits in den Bergen und wandere dort)

> Ich wandere in die Berge.

(= ich bin nicht in den Bergen, aber wandere dorthin)

Answer (score 2):

All four sentences are correct, but they mean different things.

Note, that *in + dative case* gives a place, but *in + accusative case* gives a direction.

- **In den Bergen = ein Ort** (in + Dativ = Ort)
  In the mountains = a place

  1. > Ich mache eine Wanderung in den Bergen. (Wo? - In den Bergen)
     >   I do a hike in the mountains. (Where, i.e. at which place? - In the mountains)
  2. > Ich wandere in den Bergen. (Wo? - In den Bergen)
     >   I am hiking in the mountains. (Where, i.e. at which place? - In the mountains)
- **In die Berge = eine Richtung** (in + Akkusativ = Richtung)
  To the mountains = a direction

  3. > Ich wandere in die Berge. (Wohin? - In die Berge)
     >   I am hiking to the mountains. (Where to, i.e. in which direction? - To the mountains)
  4. > Ich gehe in die Berge, um einen Ausflug zu machen. (Wohin? - In die Berge)
     >   I go to the mountains to go on a trip. (Where to, i.e. in which direction? - To the mountains)

Answer (score 1):

Um nichts auszulassen: Man könnte noch die folgenden etwas abseitigen Varianten anführen:

> Ich wandere in Bergen.

I am hiking in (the Norwegian town of) Bergen.

> Ich wandere nach Bergen.

I am hiking to (the Norwegian town of) Bergen.