# When should I use "in die Richtung" vs "in der Richtung"?

Tags: dative, accusative

> **This question also has an answer here (in German):**
>   *http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/31705*

My german is bit better now but recently one of my colleagues corrected me saying "Du sagst nicht immer in der richtung, manchmal passt in die richtung auch".

> I remember that in is always dative.

The challenge was that he could not explain me the cases in English. Could someone here explain me with an example?

Comment: The main difference is between a specification of a direction (accusative) and a location (dative); your question complicates things, because you use the translation of *direction* itself, but the dative (in der Richtung) implies a location as in *Post und Bank liegen in der (gleichen) Richtung* (Mail office and bank are sited in the same direction).

Comment: @guidot English and German questions are not considered duplicates of each other (see https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/807/25241).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*In* ***dieser/der*** *Richtung liegt der See.* 
Dativ (wo). This describes a *location*.

*In* ***diese/die*** *Richtung müssen Sie fahren, um zum See zu gelangen.* 
Akkusativ (wohin). This describes a *direction*.

*Richtung* is most often used to describe directions(that is what it means, after all), but the first example shows a locational use. Directions require the Akkusativ normally, while locations require Dativ.

Comment: Vielen dank. Ich habe jetzt völlig verstanden.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know your verbs.

- The verb you use has a need for either a direction or a location.

> Es geht in die richtige Richtung.

The verb *gehen* needs a direction where to go to. If you use the preposition **in**, that one has to take the accusative, because it's one of the nine 
**dual-way prepositions**: *an*, *auf*, *hinter*, *neben*, *in*, *über*, *unter*, *vor*, *zwischen*.

Note this *Richtung → accusative* rule does only apply to those nine prepositions. The preposition *zu* for example always takes the dative and though, it means a direction:

> Wir gehen zum Essen.

---

The verb *liegen* in contrary needs a place where something lies at.

> Es liegt in der Richtung. *(points somewhere)*

Though you are giving directions (by using the literal word *Richtung*), you used the verb *liegen*, and that means your dual-way preposition *in* has to take the dative.

Comment: Choice of accusative or dative is in most cases **not** driven by the verb. ("Ich gehe im Park"/"Ich gehe in den Park")

Comment: We could open a can of worms here. Prepositional object (which needs a direction) vs. adverbial of place.